# How to include prettyDate module in Aurelia

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia

I've installed the jquery pretty-date plugin using npm.
In Aurelia framework project, I see a new entrance in the dependencies node, in the package.json file:

```
"pretty-date": "^0.2.0"
```

I've added a new entrance into the aurelia.json file, in the dependemcies section:

```
"name": "prettyDate",
"path": "../node_modules/pretty-hrtime",
"main": "prettyDate"
```

I'm trying to import the plugin, so I can use its functions, in a common js file:

```
import { prettyDate } from 'prettyDate';
```

and then using it in a function, by:

```
return this.prettyDate.format(originalValue, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

but I keep getting:

> vendor-bundle.js:1 Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'prettyDate' of undefined

What am I missing here ?

Comment: If the package name is `pretty-date`, why is the path `../node_modules/pretty-hrtime`?

Comment: Also, when I look on npmjs.org I see roughly 3 packages related to "pretty-date". Which one specifically are you referring to?

Comment: I've decided to let it go and use another plugin, due to the fact that the prettyDate is jQuery element, which is not suitable for these kind of frameworks like Aurelia. I'll probably use moment.js